# Cannot complete upgrade of debian stretch

Tags: linux, debian

I had tried to upgrade to Debian 9, but after run

> su
>
> apt-get update
>
> apt-get upgrade
>
> apt-get dist-upgrade

I'm not able to complete the download, I getting the following erros:

> apt-get dist-upgrade

```
Reading package list ... Done203/5000
Creating dependency tree
Reading the status information ... Done
You may want to run «apt --fix-broken install» to fix it.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 adwaita-icon-theme : Depends: gtk-update-icon-cache
 aptitude : Depends: libcwidget3v5 but it is not installed
            Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0v5 (>= 2.8.0) but it is not installed
            Depends: libxapian30 but it is not installed
 gnome-icon-theme : Depends: gtk-update-icon-cache
 gparted : Depends: libatkmm-1.6-1v5 (>= 2.24.0) but it is not installed
           Depends: libglibmm-2.4-1v5 (>= 2.50.0) but it is not installed
           Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0v5 (>= 2.8.0) but it is not installed
 inkscape : Depends: libatkmm-1.6-1v5 (>= 2.24.0) but it is not installed
            Depends: libcdr-0.1-1 but it is not installed
            Depends: libglibmm-2.4-1v5 (>= 2.50.0) but it is not installed
            Depends: libgsl2 but it is not installed
            Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0v5 (>= 2.8.0) but it is not installed
            Depends: libvisio-0.1-1 but it is not installed
            Recomend: libimage-magick-perl but it is not installed
            Recomend: python-lxml but it is not installed
            Recomend: python-scour but it is not installed
 libcairomm-1.0-1v5 : Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0v5 (>= 2.2.0) but it is not installed
 libgtk-3-bin : Depends: gtk-update-icon-cache
 libgtk2.0-bin : Depends: gtk-update-icon-cache
 libgtkmm-2.4-1v5 : Depends: libatkmm-1.6-1v5 (>= 2.24.0) but it is not installed
                    Depends: libglibmm-2.4-1v5 (>= 2.48.0) but it is not installed
                    Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0v5 (>= 2.6.1) but it is not installed
 libpangomm-1.4-1v5 : Depends: libglibmm-2.4-1v5 (>= 2.48.0) but it is not installed
                  Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0v5 (>= 2.2.0) but it is not installed
E: dependsncias incumplidas. Try «apt --fix-broken install» without packages (or specify a solution).
```

and after run apt --fix-broken install

```
(Reading the database ... 118304 files or directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack ... / gtk-update-icon-cache_3.22.8-1_amd64.deb ...
There is no deviation for `deviation from / usr / sbin / update-icon-caches to /usr/sbin/update-icon-caches.gtk2 for libgtk-3-bin ', none have been removed.
dpkg-divert: attention: missing the file list file of the `libgtk-3-bin 'package, it will be assumed that the package does not have any files currently installed
Removing `deviation from /usr/share/man/man8/update-icon-caches.8.gz to /usr/share/man/man8/update-icon-caches.gtk2.8.gz per libgtk-3-bin '
dpkg-divert: error: rename requires overwriting `/usr/share/man/man8/update-icon-caches.8.gz 'with
  A different `/usr/share/man/man8/update-icon-caches.gtk2.8.gz 'file is not allowed.
dpkg: failed to process file /var/cache/apt/archives/gtk-update-icon-cache_3.22.8-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 The new pre-installation script thread returned error exit code 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/gtk-update-icon-cache_3.22.8-1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process / usr / bin / dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Anyone has an idea how can I solve this issue?

Comment: have you tried renaming `update-icon-caches.8.gz` to e.g. `update-icon-caches.8.gz.bk` then running `run apt --fix-broken install` again? If all worked fine you can delete the renamed file, otherwise rename it back to it's original name.